# Is this type of advertising counter to Halacha?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy

A recent news article reported "Soda ad blitzes conspicuously match food stamp schedules"
https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2018/06/07/soda-ad-blitzes-conspicuously-match-food-stamp-schedules-study-says/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.0677cbfa497a

Such advertisements encourage unwise spending (e.g., eating junk foor and, in the extreme, spending rent money on soda) but the specific encouraged behavior is not a sin (i.e., drinking soda).  Yet, such advertising seems to me to not be in the best interests of society.

Is there halacha related to placing such advertisements?

Comment: והיה כי יצעק אלי ושמעתי כי חנון אני

Comment: @DoubleAA The key word in Shemot 22 is translated in two common ways: afflict and exploit. Online dictionaries offer these definitions: 
afflict - to cause suffering or unhappiness to; distress greatly 
exploit - treat unfairly by using work or ideas but giving little in return
exploit - gain an advantage rather than trying to help other people or do what is right
Perhaps these concepts apply to the soda ads.  Perhaps the soda ads are are too far removed from suffering or treating unfairly.  Do you know of any responsa that support your position?

Comment: I didn't take a legal position. It's clearly a horrible thing to do. If Beit Din can prevent it or formally collect damages is a separate question from if it's immoral and if God will care

Comment: @DoubleAA. The question asks for a legal position, or at least thoughts as to what halacha might apply to this type of advertising.

Comment: Indeed it does, and I didn't post an answer